# PathLib How to extract 2nd before last item in the path?

Tags: python, path, pathlib

Example:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path("/home/user/Downloads/repo/test.txt")
>>> print(p.stem)
test
>>> print(p.name)
test.txt
```

I would like this function to return `repo`. (2nd before last item in the path)

I believe that `os.basename` is the equivalent but everything in my code is using Pathlib. Please help!

Comment: try `p.parts[-2]`, take care to either ensure the path is long enough / catch any index out of bounds issues

Comment: Why not just use `p.parent.stem`?

Answer (score 0):

Used `os.path.split(os.path.split(x)[0])[1]` and it worked!